# Automatic label plotting using pointLabel() from maptools library in R

Tags: r, r-maptools

I am trying to solve automatic label placement problem for an engineering drawing using the Simulated Annealing algorithm. I came across the `pointLabel()` function in the `maptools` library in R. However, what I found was that while the function is able to optimally place the labels, it doesn't take into account the underlying drawing. I don't want the labels to overlap with the drawing lines. Is there some way I can achieve this? Also, my labels are of varying size in terms of width and height. Is there any way in which I can specify the dimension of each label apart from the point of origin of the labels?

I don't know how to upload the requisite csv files for reproducing my work, but here's the dropbox link https://www.dropbox.com/s/85qqs4nlvm4crck/TextBoxData.rar?dl=0 to it and this is my code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(maptools)    

#Known Size of Sheet
xmin <- -357.7
xmax <- 19.3
ymin <- -90.2
ymax <- 159.7

#Read in the data
linescoords <- read.csv("Linecoords.csv")

#Coordinates translation
linescoords$X  <- linescoords$X - xmin
linescoords$Y <- linescoords$Y - ymin

#Plot the figure
xlimit <- c(-10, abs(xmin-xmax)+10 )
ylimit <- c(-10, abs(ymin-ymax)+10 )
plot(linescoords$X, linescoords$Y, "p", xlim=xlimit, ylim = ylimit)

i <- seq(1, nrow(linescoords), 2)
for(x in i){
segments(linescoords$X[x], linescoords$Y[x],
         linescoords$X[x+1], linescoords$Y[x+1])
}


#Read in text labels data
labels <- read.csv("labels.csv")

#Text labels Coordinates translation
labels$x <- labels$x - xmin
labels$y <- labels$y - ymin
labels$xminl <- labels$xminl - xmin
labels$xmaxl <- labels$xmaxl - xmin
labels$yminl <- labels$yminl - ymin
labels$ymaxl <- labels$ymaxl - ymin

#Point of Origin for labels
points(labels$x, labels$y, pch=16, col="red")

#Width & Height of labels
labels <- labels %>% mutate(width=abs(xminl-xmaxl), height=abs(yminl-ymaxl))

pointLabel(labels$x, labels$y, labels$Point)
```

Any insights would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You should try the `lineLabel` and `sp.lineLabel` functions of this same package.